# Find the number of processes using Ansible

Tags: count, ansible, process, output, ps

Below is my playbook that dumps the processes matching `.*httpd.*|.*sjsws.*|.*java.*|.*docker.*|.*node.*`

Playbook:

```
   vars:
     grepelement: ".*httpd.*|.*sjsws.*|.*java.*|.*docker.*|.*node.*"

     - name: "Check processes on destination"
       ignore_errors: yes
       command: ps auxwww
       register: ps_out

     - set_fact:
         processdump: "{{ ps_out.stdout | regex_findall(grepelement) }}"

     - set_fact:
         processdumpcount: "{{ ps_out.stdout.split() | length }}"
```

Unfortunately, although only 4 processes are running the count seems to print more than 1000s which could be the number of characters in the output.

I also tried the below but this too prints more than the number of processes running.

```
     - set_fact:
         processdumpcount: "{{ ps_out.stdout_lines | length }}"
```

I can use `command: ps auxwww | wc -l` as a solution but prefer solution with a single `ps` command.

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the length of `processdump` register for the count **not** `ps_out.stdout_lines`

```
  - set_fact:
      processdumpcount: "{{ processdump  | length }}"
```

Note that `ps_out` is holding on to all the processes running on the system and later you are operating `ps_out` with `regex_findall` to filter out the matching processes to `processdump`. you need to take `length` of `processdump` register.

**Minimal working example:**

My system process counts:

```
 ps auxwww |wc -l
287
 ps auxwww |grep -E ".*httpd.*|.*sjsws.*|.*java.*|.*docker.*|.*node.*" |grep -v grep |wc -l
3
```

playbook:

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  #  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    grepelement: ".*httpd.*|.*sjsws.*|.*java.*|.*docker.*|.*node.*"
  tasks:
  - name: "Check processes on destination"
    ignore_errors: yes
    command: ps auxwww
    register: ps_out

  - set_fact:
     processdump: "{{ ps_out.stdout | regex_findall(grepelement) }}"

  - set_fact:
      processdumpcount: "{{ processdump  | length }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ processdumpcount }}"
```

Above playbook would result in:

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check processes on destination] *******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "3"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I need the length after the `regex_findall` hence the answer wont help.

Comment: sorry, I pasted wrong task by mistake. Try the updated answer, place this after `regex_fileall` task.